# How to recenter an object's origin?

Tags: modeling, transforms

So, I'm working creating a lamp... yes, newbie here.

After modeling for a bit, I noticed that my point of origin was no longer the center of my object:

[image]

How to I reset an object origin point to the center of it's geometry?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> (perhaps the longest shortcut in Blender) and select *Origin to Geometry*. Or, instead, open the Toolshelf by pressing <kbd>T</kbd> and press the *Set Origin* button in the *Tools* tab, subsection *Edit*.

Depending on how you imagine the 'Center' of your object, you might instead want to choose *Origin to Center of Mass*. The difference is that it calculates the center point based on the volume of the mesh, rather than the average location of vertices as *Origin to Geometry* does.

Visually, the difference is this (blue dot is the new origin point):

[image: to Geometry vs to Center of Mass]

**UPDATE** *for Blender 2.8*

Press the *Object* button at the bottom of the 3D view and see the *Set Origin...* sub-menu:

Here you can find both the *Origin to Geometry* and two similar *Origin to Center of Mass* options.

Comment: There are other four key shortcuts too, e.g. `Ctrl Shift Alt M`.. :P Anyway, I edited your answer, feel free to rollback if you disagree with my edits.

Comment: Are you sure, that one doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: It selects non-manifold geometry in edit mode.

Comment: Oh, nice; But I looked through the user preferences and found no such shortcut

Comment: Sometimes neither of these two is sufficient; in that case in edit mode select whole object (`A`), `G`rab it, move it to such a location that the desired center is at 0,0,0. Then in Object mode set 3D cursor coords to 0,0,0 and then `Ctrl Alt Shift C`, Origin to 3D Cursor.

Comment: @SF. What do you mean by not sufficient? If you want to position the origin, then you can use the 3D cursor, but otherwise, I don't get what you mean.

Comment: @someonewithpc: Just recently, I had a part that was a tube 3 meters long, hollowed out one meter deep through one end.  I needed the origin squat in the middle of its length.  Center of mass would shift the origin towards the full end where most of mass is concentrated. Center of geometry would gravitate towards the bunch of vertices of the bore hole (versus the "plain" full end). Putting the cursor 1.5m from one end did the trick.

Comment: @SF. Oh, ok. In that case, standard practice is to select the circles at both end and snap the cursor to them and then move the origin to the cursor.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Click on Set Origin, then click Origin to Geometry.

Answer (score 6):

1. <kbd>RMB [image: RMB]</kbd> on the object in *object-mode*
2. Select *Set Origin*
3. Select *Origin to Geometry*.

Comment: This to me is the most intuitive approach, yet considering how earlier Blender has scarred some of us to only go for the most cumbersome approach, it didn't even occur to me to right click in 3.0 to see what "options" the object has. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Other way if you want change arbitrary the center is selecting a face or a point, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> (move the cursor to this position) and from object mode set the origin to 3D cursor.

Answer (score 2):

To complete Someonewithpc's answer, since 2.8 you can manipulate the origin itself: go into the *Options* panel, enable the *Transform Affect Only Origins* option, now you can move (or rotate or scale) the origin. Don't forget to disable the option once you're glad:

[image]

[image]