# How to move object's origin to mesh?

Tags: objects, transforms

The question is vague, and I apologize for that. I don't know how to make the dot that has the transform tools, appear in the middle of the mesh like it is supposed to be. I would appreciate some assistance with this.

<sub>the dot with the arrows below the object</sub>
[image]

Comment: This little dot is called "origin" of the object. See this question: [How to recenter an object's origin?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14294/how-to-recenter-an-objects-origin)