# How can I move an object along it's local axis?

Tags: objects, edit-mode

I'm looking to move an object, just when I edit it, along its own axis rather than the world's axis.  Is this possible?  Also is origin synonymous with axis?

Comment: the world origin is the point where the 3 axis(x,y,z) intersect..  not to be confused with the [object's origin](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14296/2816)

Comment: It is preferred to only ask one question at a time, you can ask as many as you want. An axis is part of [the coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) used to define locations in 3D space. The [origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origin_%28mathematics%29) is the centre of that system. In 3D graphics, "object origin" is often used and refers to the object's location in space, which is the zero point used for the (mesh) data for that object.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I can thing of two ways:

1) In the 3D view Editor header you can choose the transform orientation

2) lets say you want to move in in the local x axis: hit <kbd>G</kbd>  <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd>

Comment: Thanks.  So is axis and origin synonymous?  I see origin quite a bit and it seems they are simply referring to the axis of the object(s).

Comment: https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/origns.html