# Pivot point at cetner when importing .stl from Solidworks

Tags: import, scale

)

When I am importing the many part of an assembly from solid works to blender, I get the pivot point for the assembly at the cetner of the scene! Then I am not able (with my current poor skills) to properly scale the individual parts of it.

I would imagine there is a way of doing this so that the pivot point is at the center of the assembly/individual objects I import?

Have a good one!

[image: image here]

Comment: Set Origin parameter on the Toolshelf on the left (or from Spacebar menu) will change pivot point to the one you choose. From the other hand pivot might be changed before import as it's likely set to the center of the scene (so moving objects to the center could work). Choose the way which works

Comment: Thanks! From your comment I found this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14294/how-to-recenter-an-objects-origin/14296. So fully helpful! :-)