# Rotating a cylinder

Tags: cycles-render-engine, objects, constraints

I have a label around a bottle which i would like rotate (either the entire bottle or just the label. Can anyone point me in the right direction, so to speak! [image]

Comment: @cegaton Does this help? Thank you.

Comment: @cegaton The point of origin of the cylinder is no longer showing so I am unable to rotate around this. Is there a way to accurately determine this once more? Also is this the best way to do this?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14294/how-to-recenter-an-objects-origin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rotate the texture.

Add a mapping node, then you can move the location (size, and rotation) of the image used as part of the material.

[image]