# Find center of geometry of a set of objects

Tags: edit-mode

I have a Blender model composed of several objects.
I would like to move the 3D cursor to the geometry center of the model (=> one common points for all objects of this model).

I've tried to select all objects and then Shit+S: Cursor to selected. 
Result: it seems that cursor goes to center of mass of all my selected objects but not in center of geometry of all my selected objects.

[image]

How can I achieved that ? Thank you.

Comment: what do you precisely mean by center of geometry and center of mass.
I think these concepts are misused. can you provide a picture of what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

2.8 Update, now you can edit more than one object simultaneously..

- In Object Mode, select relevant objects
- <kbd>Tab</kbd> switch to Edit Mode
- <kbd>A</kbd> select all, if necesary
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> Cursor to selected.

Answer (score 0):

I think selecting the object and pressing Shift+Ctrl+Alt+C would do the trick.
Similar question - [How to recenter an object's origin?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14294/how-to-recenter-an-objects-origin)

Comment: Thanks. I already tried this action but what I want is a unique point at geometry center for all objects. Not one geometry center point for each object. I updated my post to be more clear.

Comment: Try selecting all the objects and pressing Ctrl+J to make in one single mesh. Then you can press Shift+S or Shift+Ctrl+Alt+C. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Thanks. Complete solution: 1-Select all objects/bones, 2-Ctrl+j, 3-Select object, 4-Ctrl+Shift+Alt+C: origin to geometry, 5-Shit+S: cursor to selected, 6-Ctrl+Z four times (re-split objects & keep cursor at center of geometry of all objects).

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are half way there.

If it is just a few objects... in object mode just make a copy of all of them, select them all, right-click (in scene) and join them. Switch to edit mode, select all vertices (press A) and then "Snap cursor to selection" (Shift+S for snap menu). Switch back to object mode, delete the joined object and you can use the cursor as a centered reference point.

This will work for any number of objects, but I can image it gets impractical the higher the count.

In that case... find a plugin for that.