# how to know which pivot object is using (Local/World)

Tags: coordinates

i have 2 identical objects with identical location numbers, but theyre located in different places. this is so annoying to deal with. how do i see the world coordinates? here is example of what i mean.
to counter the blender random coord picking i have to move Freeze M0_LOD0 object by 100m on X scale.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you understand that the final location of some object could be matrix products of many objects including the parent object?

Comment: i got no clue about what kind of matrix thingies are u reffering to.

Comment: Both object's origins are defined by the dot in the middle, which provides the center/pivot for any transforms, it does not necessarily relate at all to the position of the geometry of the object. You may however find https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14294/how-to-recenter-an-objects-origin useful.

Answer (score 1):

Snap Cursor to Selected to see the coordinates.  Then look at the cursor coordinates.
<kbd>Shift S</kbd>

That cursor information is already showing in your images in your original question.

Comment: oh, so no easy way to move 2 objects, but to pull out calculator every time?

Comment: @Dage Not quite, Relative movement [G X 20] | Absolute Movement: Position Cursor, then snap object to cursor.