# All my objects transforms are the same

Tags: objects, transforms, properties

I've imported a model from an .obj file. It imports fine, and I can see all the separate mesh objects that make up the model. But when I look at their object properties, all the transforms are the same for each mesh. I'm not really sure how that happened or what's going on; I wouldn't mind, but I'm exporting it via fbx to import into a game and it's screwing that process up somehow. Is there some local/global coordinate distinction I'm missing somewhere?

Comment: Are you looking to merge them all into one object, or do you want the centre to be inside each separare object? It is possible to set the centre of an object, however you would have to do it manually for each object as far as i'm aware.

Comment: do you want the centre to be inside each separare object? - I think that's exactly what I want, for each object to be centred on its own origin. Is there no way of doing that automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select all desired objects in *3d View* (*Object Mode*) and go to *Object > Set Orgin* and choose Origin to *Center of Mass (Volume)*:

[image]

You can also call the operator using the *Search Menu*:

1. Press <kbd>F3</kbd>
2. Search for **Set Origin**
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Select **Origin to Center of Mass(Volume)**

Read more here: [How to recenter an object's origin?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14294/how-to-recenter-an-objects-origin)

Comment: That does exactly what I wanted, thanks!

Comment: No need for that script. *Object > Set Origin* works for all objects in selection...

Comment: Yes i just noticed :)