# How to set origin to geometry center

Tags: modeling

I selected a model and use "Origin to Geometry" to set origin. As a result, the yellow point move to the head part of model, instead of the model's center.

So it's clear that blender default the geometry center based on the volume of the mesh. On my case, there are more meshes on the head of model.
[image]

Image reference:
[How to recenter an object's origin?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14294/how-to-recenter-an-objects-origin)

If I use "Origin to Center of Mass (volumn)", the yellow point will be on the center of course.

But if my project requires that I must use "Origin to Geometry", how can I let the point on the center of model?

Comment: It sounds like you’re saying you need Origin to Geometry to do what Origin to Center of Mass does. Why on earth can’t you just use Origin to Center of Mass?

Comment: my project requires that I must use "Origin to Geometry"

Comment: So, what is the definition of "Origin to Geometry"?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use different center method to set origin.

[image]