Import from Sketchup to Blender
I am new to Blender and would like to make an animation for the first time, animating is pretty clear, only I had made a 3D file in Sketchup and exported it as a Collada file.
Only every time I import it into Blender, many parts are shifted apart, also you see all crazy dotted lines. I'm sure you guys know what this means, how could I fix this?
Something with axes? How do I get rid of those lines and that it really is a part, because even with rotation it doesn't take the center point, but somewhere outside it.
Thanks for the help!^^


Hello and welcome. Please don't ask more than one question per post. Use the [edit] link below your post, to break this into multiple posts so that each focuses on a single issue. Make as many separate questions as necessary.

I see that it are relationship lines, but how can I move those orange dots to the parts?

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14294/how-to-recenter-an-objects-origin
